# files dissapear when I run mv command

Tags: command-line, shell, mv

I use the below command to move files:

```
mv *.gz directoryname
```

but directory name has spell mistake and the file with directory name has been generated with unknown format. And I lost my file.

How can I get them back? is there anyway to get them from the directoryname which is generated while running `mv` command.

Please let me know if you want me to more clear on this.

Thanks

Comment: How important is this data?  In DOS-like systems (Windows), such a thing can often delete all-but-one of the files.  Unix "mv" is less prone to this, but if this data is important, don't just "try mv directoryname *.gz", or try other such things that might write to the hard drive, until you make a disk image to back things up.  What operating system/shell are you using?  What if you type: `find . -iname *.gz`?  What if you type: `find / iname *.gz`?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that your expression `*.gz` matches just one file beacuse if that regex matches more than one file then your terminal would show a message like...

> mv: target **directoryname** is not a directory

Did you try to run the next command?

```
mv directoryname *.gz
```

Comment: It contains multiple files and command does not thrown any error.

Comment: It contains multiple files and command does not thrown any error. And I tried command which you suggest but no luck.

Comment: that regex matches more than one .gz file? And the result is one file without extension? Do you use shell? I need more information please

Comment: yes *.gz have more files and it generated single file without any extension. yes I used it in shell.

Comment: That't what i said.. "If you specify multiple files, the target must be a directory"

[mv command](https://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/mv.1.asp)

You get a successfull completion of the command?